# Qt update value every second

Tags: c++, c, qt, qt5

i want to update the value of a label every one second from a command, so been trying to display it via while loop...however the UI does not load and does not work...

any suggestions/help would be appreciated...

below is the test code...

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QProcess>
#include <QString>
#include <QtCore/QTextStream>
#include <QRegularExpression>
#include <QRegularExpressionMatch>
#include <QRegularExpressionValidator>

#include <iostream>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent)
, ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    txMessage();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::txMessage()
{
    QString command = "bash -c \"netstat -i | grep ens33 | awk \'{print $3}\'\"";
    int temp = 0;
    droc = new QProcess;
    while (temp != 1)
    {
        droc->start(command);
        droc->waitForFinished();
        QString value = droc->readAllStandardOutput();
        ui->label_3->setText(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You must always return control to the event loop. Your `while` loop will make your application unresponsive.
2. You're leaking the process instance.
3. At the very least you could use `awk` to its full potential: `netstat -i | awk '/ens33/ { print $3; exit 0 }'`. Your command string is invalid anyway, since the `\'` is not a valid C/C++ escape sequence. You don't need to escape single quotes.
4. You're invoking three extra processes for no reason at all (bash, grep and awk). Qt is perfectly capable of extracting the data you want.
5. You're allocating things on the heap for no good reason either. Note the absence of any explicit `new` and `delete` in the code below. At the very least, you should be using a `QScopedPointer` or `std::unique_ptr` (but **never** `std::auto_ptr`!).

The following self-contained example works on both Qt 4 and Qt 5.

```
#include <QLabel>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QBasicTimer>
#include <QProcess>
#include <QApplication>

class Widget : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
    QHBoxLayout m_layout;
    QLabel m_label;
    QBasicTimer m_timer;
    QProcess m_process;
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent * ev) {
        if (ev->timerId() == m_timer.timerId()) txMessage();
    }
    void txMessage() {
        m_timer.stop();
        m_process.start("netstat", QStringList() << "-i", QProcess::ReadOnly);
    }
    Q_SLOT void finished(int rc) {
        startTimer();
        if (rc != 0) {
            m_label.setText("Error");
        } else {
            QString output = QString::fromLocal8Bit(m_process.readAll());
            QStringList lines = output.split('\n', QString::SkipEmptyParts);
            foreach (QString line, lines) {
                if (!line.contains("ens33")) continue;
                QStringList args = line.split(' ', QString::SkipEmptyParts);
                if (args.count() >= 3) {
                    m_label.setText(args.at(3));
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        m_label.setText("...");
    }
    void startTimer() {
#if QT_VERSION>=QT_VERSION_CHECK(5,0,0)
        m_timer.start(1000, Qt::CoarseTimer, this);
#else
        m_timer.start(1000, this);
#endif
    }
public:
    Widget(QWidget * parent = 0) : QWidget(parent), m_layout(this), m_label("...") {
        m_layout.addWidget(&m_label);
        startTimer();
        connect(&m_process, SIGNAL(finished(int)), SLOT(finished(int)));
    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: you're right. I forgot that in Qt children remove themselves from their parents on destruction.

Comment: @IvanGrynko It's nothing to do with Qt, it is how C++ works. When you have `class C : public D { A a; B b; };`, the following destructors run, in order: `B::~B, A::~A, C::~C, D::~D`. Imagine now that `D` is a `QObject`.

Comment: I'm shocked that this answer has been down-voted twice. Not only does it clearly explain the issues, but provides a complete working example.

Comment: @KubaOber, what frustrates me most is that downvoting without explaining why is definitely counterproductive. I would like to see downvoting forcibly justified, but I guess that's never going to happen.

Comment: @Merlin069 There was an explanation to one of the downvotes. It was wrong and has since been deleted. The downvote can't be removed since I didn't edit the question in the meantime (and I won't just to deal with a downvote, I don't have much to add at the moment). The question is still net 16 rep, so who cares :)

Comment: Fair enough, though I didn't upvote through pity...the answer was to the point and deserved ;O)

Answer (score -2):

Issue 1. Your loop is infinite, because value of `tmp` is not changed inside the loop.

Issue 2. You block the UI thread. The simplest solution is to add

```
while( true ) {
    ...
    QCoreApplication::processEvents();
    if( droc->waitForFinished( 10 ) )
        break;
}
```

inside your loop. But it's not 'qt-style' and can lead to hard-to-detect bugs.

The best solution is to `connect` `QProcess::finished` signal to a method and read standard output there.

**NOTE:** the gold rule of async programming - never block the main thread for a long time.

Comment: This is bad advice. `processEvents` (and `exec`) recurse into the event loop and are a source of hard to track bugs. Don't use them.